# linked image doesnt show up in HTML

Tags: html, css, image

The linked image won't show up in HTML. If I click the source in Python, it shows up so I know the referencing is OK. This shows up in the terminal: `"GET /öppettider.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404`.

HTML:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} {% block content%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <h3>Öppettider</h3>
      <img src="öppettider.jpg" alt="Skövde Skatehall öppettider">
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I tried moving the `.jpg` to different directories.

Comment: `404` means `Not Found` so clearly the referencing is **not** OK.

Comment: There is a difference between how a file name in a Python source file is resolved in your IDE, how a URL is resolved in a web browser, and how a web server converts a URL to a response. There's not enough information in your question to determine what (if any) URL the image actually has.

Comment: The only way your img url will work is if the image is in the same directory as this python view. Otherwise you need to reference the directory the image is in.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if I understood your question or not, but if there is no image, please look at the way of image, absolute or relative. Like this "./"

Comment: Hi, could you please write more about what it means? [How to give good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: i think maybe the problem in paths?
im not sure